# Check File Path Condition

Tags: c#

Why does my code won't trigger the else condition? If I can't locate my file it won't prompt, but if it locate it prompts.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Personal Folders\";

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path,
            "*3.zip*",   //set sa batch
            SearchOption.AllDirectories);


        // Display all the files.

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            bool exist = File.Exists(file);

            if (exist == true) 
            { 
              MessageBox.Show("File Located : " + Convert.ToString(file));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Cant Locate :");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: GetFiles returns the file names that it matches with the given pattern (it means the files are physically exist) and you are simply iterating the collection returned by GetFiles. In this case your code will never go into the else part.

Comment: is there anyway code that can search a file in the path ? if not exist it will prompt does file not located and some file thats located will proceed ? 

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path,
            "*3.zip*",   //set sa batch
            SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

this returns the files which are present in that directory with the matching pattern, so checking for file exists does not make sense anyways and hence your else is never executing.

Comment: is there anyway code that can search a file in the path ? if not exist it will prompt does file not located and some file thats located will proceed ? thanks in advance

Comment: `File.Exists` is the method which accepts a file path and returns `true` if file exists else `false`.

Comment: @user3446835 Please mark this as answer if this is solving your problem. Happy coding!